# Send an email using office-js in Outlook add-in

Tags: node.js, outlook, ms-office, office-js, outlook-addin

I'm building an Outlook add-in and I'd like to send an email from the add-in itself,
Is it possible with office-js?

My goal is to allow the users select a person from a list on the add-in, when selected I want to send an email to that person, by click.

I can see that it has MessageCompose interface but it seems it allows only to edit the content of the email.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=outlook-js-1.8

I know that Yesware have an Outlook add-in that sends an email by click and I'm trying to accomplish something similar.

Thank you

Comment: It should be possible as you can directly hit the api and do the needful

Comment: @deepakthomas Could you elaborate where should I look up? I looked at the documentation and didn't get across something like that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send mail directly from Outlook Add-in as Outlook doesn't provide this permission. The maximum you can edit the mail content and mail have to be triggered by the User itself.

If you want to send Mail then you have to implement Mail sending service or better use API's of popular providers like MailChimp or Sendgrid